# Getting Error 400 when using Authentication Broker in Win 8 App for Stackexchange API

Tags: vb.net, oauth, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to connect to StackExchange API using OAuth. 
So far i've been able to get a token and retrive data that does not require authentication.
When i try do query that uses the authentication, i'm getting error 400 - Bad request.
Heres the code:

```
    Dim Key As String = "(app_key)"

    Dim RequestURL As String = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/questions?access_token=" & Token & "key=" & Key & "&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackapps"

    Dim Handler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler()
    If Handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression Then 
           Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    End If

    Dim HttpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient(Handler)

    Dim query = Await HttpClient.GetAsync(RequestURL)

    If query.IsSuccessStatusCode = True Then
         '(query.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
    End If
```

Tried using only key, only access token, or none in the request, but received the same error. Also tried adding "OAuth" header and "access_token":

```
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", Token)
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("access_token", Token)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out a was using the wrong key. I managed to make it work by using both access_token and key in the RequestUrl, not using the request headers.